# Reading and writing the same file simultaneosly with c++

Tags: c++, file, fstream, getline

I'm trying to read and write a file as I loop through its lines. At each line, I will do an evaluation to determine if I want to write it into the file or skip it and move onto the next line. This is a basically a skeleton of what I have so far.

```
void readFile(char* fileName)
{
    char line[1024];
    fstream file("test.file", ios::in | ios::out);

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        while(file.getline(line,MAX_BUFFER))
        {

            //evaluation

            file.seekg(file.tellp());
            file << line;
            file.seekp(file.tellg());
        }
    }
}
```

As I'm reading in the lines, I seem to be having issues with the starting index of the string copied into the line variable. For example, I may be expecting the string in the line variable to be "000/123/FH/" but it actually goes in as "123/FH/". I suspect that I have an issue with file.seekg(file.tellp()) and file.seekp(file.tellg()) but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: If you are performing random access in a file, you generally want to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: `file.seekg(file.tellp());` is a no-op. File streams have a single position used both for reading and writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from your code <sup>[1]</sup> and problem description what is in the file and why you expect "000/123/FH/", but I can state that the `getline` function is a buffered input, and you don't have code to access the buffer.  In general, it is not recommended to use buffered and unbuffered i/o together because it requires deep knowledge of the buffer mechanism and then relies on that mechanism not to change as libraries are upgraded.

You appear to want to do byte or character<sup>[2]</sup> level manipulation.  For small files, you should read the entire file into memory, manipulate it, and then overwrite the original, requiring an open, read, close, open, write, close sequence.  For large files you will need to use `fread` and/or some of the other lower level C library functions.

The best way to do this, since you are using C++, is to create your own class that handles reading up to and including a line separator <sup>[3]</sup> into one of the off-the-shelf circular buffers (that use malloc or a plug-in allocator as in the case of STL-like containers) or a circular buffer you develop as a template over a statically allocated array of bytes (if you want high speed an low resource utilization).  The size will need to be at least as large as the longest line in the later case. <sup>[4]</sup>

Either way, you would want to add to the class to open the file in binary mode and expose the desired methods to do the line level manipulations to an arbitrary line.  Some say (and I personally agree) that taking advantage of Bjarne Stroustrup's class encapsulation in C++ is that classes are easier to test carefully.  Such a line manipulation class would encapsulate the random access C functions and unbuffered i/o and leave open the opportunity to maximize speed, while allowing for plug-and-play usage in systems and applications.

**Notes**

[1] The seeking of the current position is just testing the functions and does not yet, in the current state of the code, re-position the current file pointer.

[2] Note that there is a difference between character and byte level manipulations in today's computing environment where utf-8 or some other unicode standard is now more common than ASCII in many domains, especially that of the web.

[3] Note that line separators are dependent on the operating system, its version, and sometimes settings.

[4] The advantage of circular buffers in terms of speed is that you can read more than one line using fread at a time and use fast iteration to find the next end of line.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading and writing to the same file you might end up of having duplicate lines in the file.

You could find [this](https://programmingdimension.wordpress.com/2015/04/30/seekg-tellg-seekp-tellp/) very useful. Imagine your 1st time of reaching the while loop and starting from the beginning of the file you do `file.getline(line, MAX_BUFFER)`. Now the get pointer (for reading) moves `MAX_BUFFER` places from the beginning of the file (your starting point).

After you've determine to write back to the file `seekp()` helps to specify with respect to a reference point the location you want to write to, syntax: `file.seekp(num_bytes,"ref");` where `ref` will be `ios::beg(beginning), ios::end, ios::cur`  (current position in file).

As in your code after reading, find a way to use `MAX_BUFFER` to refer to a location with respect to a reference.

```
 while(file.good())
        {
            file.getline(line,MAX_BUFFER);
            ...
            if(//for some reasone you want to write back)
            {
                 // set put-pointer to location for writing
                file.seekp(num_bytes, "ref");
                file << line;
                
             }
            //set get-pointer to desired location for the next read

            file.seekg(num_bytes, "ref");
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from Douglas Daseeco's response, I resolved my issue by simply reading the existing file, writing its lines into a new file, then renaming the new file to overwrite the original file. Below is a skeleton of my solution.

```
char line[1024];

ifstream inFile("test.file");
ofstream outFile("testOut.file");

if(inFile.is_open() && outFile.is_open())
{               
    while(inFile.getline(line,1024))
    {

        // do some evaluation

        if(keep)
        {
            outFile << line;
            outFile << "\n";
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();
    rename("testOut.file","test.file");
}
```